# Getting Photos From Firebase Storage based on UID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm facing an issue.
I'm getting photos through UID, 
but issue is in firebase database where images are replacing 
if I use the push then application didn't get images from firebase

[Firebase Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvBit.jpg)

If I remove push from database then images will be show, but as you can see that images will overlap everytime user upload image

Here is my code for onActivityResult

```
 @Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            final FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                TitleName=title.getText().toString();
                progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading .....");
                progressDialog.show();
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                StorageReference filePath = storageReference.child("Photos").child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid()).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

                filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Uri downloadPath = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(downloadPath).centerCrop().into(imageView);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DONE" + TitleName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        //creating the upload object to store uploaded image details
                        Upload upload = new Upload(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(), TitleName);

                        //adding an upload to firebase database
                     //   String uploadId = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                        mDatabase.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid())***.push().***setValue(upload);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });

            }



        }
```

If i remove push from

```
mDatabase.child(currentFirebaseUser.getUid())***.push().***setValue(upload);
```

then images will be show on recyclerView.

Any suggestions?

ShowImagesActivity

```
public class ShowImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //recyclerview object
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    //adapter object
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    //database reference
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    //progress dialog
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    //list to hold all the uploaded images
    private List<Upload> uploads;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_view);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        uploads = new ArrayList<>();

        //displaying progress dialog while fetching images
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading your memories ...");
        progressDialog.show();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);

        //adding an event listener to fetch values
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //dismissing the progress dialog
                progressDialog.dismiss();

                //iterating through all the values in database
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                    uploads.add(upload);
                }
                //creating adapter
                adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), uploads);

                //adding adapter to recyclerview
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
    }
```

Constants.java

```
   public static final String DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads";
 public static final String STORAGE_PATH_UPLOADS = "uploads/";
```

Adapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Upload> uploads;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Upload> uploads) {
        this.uploads = uploads;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_images, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Upload upload = uploads.get(position);

       holder.textViewName.setText(upload.getName());

        Glide.with(context).load(upload.getUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return uploads.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

           textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

upload.java

```
public class Upload{

    public String name;
    public String url;

    // Default constructor required for calls to
    // DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    public Upload() {
    }

    public Upload( String url, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url= url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
```

Comment: I think I understand your question, but I want to clarify: you're saying you want each user to be able to have multiple images which display in a recyclerView, but the way that the code works right now, if you use `push()`, the images don't show up in the recyclerView. If you don't use `push()`, it works, but any new image uploaded just overrides the first since it just updates that node where the image was? Can you update your code to include your recyclerView?

Comment: @JenPerson exactly. i'll update my code in a bit